# Lifetime of threading.Timer after exiting scope

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Say that I have a function that starts a `Timer` to call some other method `foo`:

```
def set_a_timer():
    my_timer = threading.Timer(1200, foo)
    my_timer.start()
    ...
    return None
```

Now, this function will return well before the Timer finishes, and might not ever be called again in my program until after those 1200 seconds are up. The program *will* keep running the whole time.

I know that garbage collection tends to take care of removing out-of-scope variables. This means that I will not be able to access `my_timer` ever again in the program. That's fine - all I need is for it to execute in 1200 seconds. But will it still execute `foo` after those 1200 seconds, or will it be cleaned up by the garbage collector before it has a chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: the timer will still run.

The long answer is that you’re confusing variables and values here. Variables go out of scope, but that doesn’t do anything to the value. (And the same for `del`; it just deletes the variable, not the value.)

It’s only when the last reference to a value goes away that the value becomes garbage. (In CPython, if the value isn’t involved in a reference cycle, this means it gets destroyed immediately; in most other implementations, it gets destroyed a bit later—as soon as the GC notices it.)

The `Timer` class is a subclass of `Thread`. Threads work by calling a `run` method in a background thread. That method’s stack frame has references to whatever it needs, like the function object itself, and all local variables, just like every function does, so those values won’t become garbage until that method finishes. One of those locals is `self`, so the `Timer` object itself is still referenced and therefore not garbage.

(If you look at the source to `Timer`—which is linked from the docs—you can see that what its `run` method does is basically just sleep waiting on an `Event` for 1200 seconds, then call your `foo` function.)

If you want to see when the `Timer` object gets destroyed, you can subclass it and add a `__del__` method that prints a message (or even have it print the whole stack at that point).